# PDF reader app that remembers the last page you were on?

Tags: ebook-reader, pdf, dropbox

- I usually access my PDFs via the DropBox app on my phone.
- Every time I open the same PDF it starts back at page 1.

**Is there a way to set up the Android Adobe Reader app to remember the last page I was on?**

**If not, is there another PDF reader app that has this option?**

Comment: Do you need the pdf format ? Or can you convert it to epub ( so that you can use the readers on Android - they remember the last page you read when 'closing' the book ).

Comment: The problem here is that you're using the DropBox app, which downloads the file every time you open it (to a temp filename), instead of syncing the files ahead of time. If you use something like Dropsync (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en), you'll use more storage on your phone, but the files will be local, and when you re-open, you'll be at the same point in the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dropbox wasn't made to be a PDF reader, instead it's an application to have your files wherever you go. So I have two great suggestions for you:

- [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader) - This is the best PDF reading application I ever seen for Android. I use it every time I need to read any kind of PDF on my Motorola Droid.
- [Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader) - A free alternative for ezPDF. Made by Adobe of course, which is very good to read your PDFs on-the-go too.

Both will restore from the place that you left

Comment: I use the Adobe Reader but I open my PDF files from the DropBox app. When I use Adobe Reader in conjunction with DropBox it does not remember the last page. Is this a DropBox issue?

Comment: @KenB Yes, the DropBox application won't work with Adobe Reader. I suggest you to download the PDF to your device and then open it using a File Explorer

Comment: Very disappointed, the whole purpose of DropBox is having a doc in the cloud and not worrying about particular clients. Oh well, thanks for the information.

Comment: @KenB: Dropbox stores files you have downloaded to the dropbox folder in your sd card.

Comment: Adobe Reader doesn't remember the last page you were on.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a good free pdf reader with similar functionality?

I tried Adobe Reader as well as quick pdf and it doesn't work. Every time I have to scroll down to the page I read before.

Comment: @GeroldMeisinger it works for Adobe Acrobat Reader in combination with Google Drive

Answer (score 5):

[Aldiko](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aldiko.android&hl=en) is an eBook reader that reads PDFs as well, remember the last page you were at and on top of that allows you to set bookmarks, something that Adobe Reader and most other readers I tried won't let you do.

Bookmarks are a must have for me so I chose Aldiko.

Answer (score 3):

[Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) will sync pdf files from Google Drive and resume from where you left off across multiple Android devices.

Comment: Note that for the PDF features you will need the [paid version of Moon+ reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp). Apart from that: I can confirm this :)

Comment: position synchronization is terrible on Moon+ Reader

Answer (score 1):

[qPDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qoppa.activities.viewer) does remember the last page read in a PDF document. It's free and available for download from Google Play.

Comment: You appear to be affiliated with the product you're recommending, please see the [FAQ section on self-promotion](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) and in future please disclose this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader) app.

Comment: Adobe Reader will NOT restore you to your previous page. I'm on Android 4.0 on a tablet, it always goes back to the first page. Also as far as I know there's no bookmark feature, Adobe's fast and well known, but the Android version is not as good as the other competitors.